# Stop users from looping Ajax requests in the browser console

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a small security issue with my website currently. I made a public chat that uses Ajax to post to a php file who then handles it and sends that chat message to the database. Then its returned to the js file and its displayed. But an issue im having is that users can set an interval loop and just send infinite ajax requests to my database and then overload it with random messages.

I have tried limiting the amount of times messages can be sent per minute but its no real use. This is the Javascript code responsible responsible for sending the AJAX requests. If I need to provide the PHP I can if its needed.

```js
var spammI = 0;

function sendChat(message) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    spammI = 0;
  }, 3000);

  if (spammI != 1) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'handlers/ajax.php?command=new_message',
      data: {
        message: message
      },
    });
    clearInput();
    spammI = 1;
  } else {
    alert("Messages can only be sent once every 3 seconds!");
  }
};

function loadChat() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'handlers/ajax.php?command=load_message',
    data: {
      loadChat: "Load"
    },
    success: function(response) {
      insertData(response);
    }
  })
}
```

I really hope someone here can figure out a solution seeing as this is a pretty big issue for me.

Comment: Why is your server-side code accepting _empty_ messages to begin with?

Comment: Sorry i reprashed its just random messages with empty meaning sorry.

Comment: _“I have tried limiting the amount of times messages can be sent per minute but its no real use.”_ - trying anything like that on the client side is of course of no use. If I don’t like what your timeout-spamcheck-thingie is doing … well then I copy&paste only the AJAX request part. If anything, you need to implement some logic to control this on the server side.

Comment: You need to do the rate limiting on the server, not on the client, as it's trivial to get around the latter. Also note that for a chat system you should really be using sockets, not AJAX.

Comment: Alright I will try to implement some rate limiting. As for the fact im using AJAX its because im required to use it. Thanks for help